# How can I set the path of saved program in Nodejs command prompt?

Tags: node.js

How can I set the path of program (saved in "C:\Users\Saurabh\Downloads\NodeJS") in Node command prompt? Please help me out fellow humans! Like the very first line in the example pic-

[Command Prompt Node js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zsbs.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "saved program"?

Comment: Actually I meant where I saved that program and want to see the path of program. like in the pic's first line. I've already written the sample program and saved in C:\Users\Saurabh\Downloads\NodeJS.

Comment: There is no `C:\Users\Saurabh\Downloads` in your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

According to the Node'js doc you can write :

`console.log(__dirname); // => C:\Users\Saurabh\Downloads`

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Comment: I'm a newbie. Please elaborate Sir!. For reference you can see the attached pic (the first line), where the program is saved.

Comment: I will not write your progam. I just tell you that you can find the full path of your program in the variable __dirname. Nothing difficult even for a newbie :-)